# how can i eliminate duplicates in gridview?

Tags: sql, duplicates

i am retrieving data from three tables for my requirement so i wrote the following query

i was getting correct result but the problem is records are repeated whats the problem in

that query.  i am binding result of query to grid view control. please help me

```
SELECT DISTINCT (tc.coursename), ur.username, uc. DATE, 'Paid' AS Status
  FROM tblcourse tc, tblusereg ur, dbo.UserCourse uc
 WHERE tc.courseid IN (SELECT ur1.courseid
                         FROM dbo.UserCourse ur1
                        WHERE ur1.userid = @userid)
   AND ur.userid = @userid
   AND uc. DATE IS NOT NULL
   AND ur.course - id = uc.course - id
```

Comment: *records are repeated* Please post some of those records. I would be hard pressed to believe any DBMS's `DISTINCT` functionality started failing.

Answer (score 3):

There is no JOIN between tblcourse tc,tblusereg ur. So you get a cross join despite the IN (which is actually a JOIN)

DISTINCT works on the whole row too: not one column.

Note: you mention dbo.UserCourse twice but use different column names courseid and [course-id]

Rewritten with JOINs.

```
select distinct
    tc.coursename, ur.username, uc.[date], 'Paid' as [Status] 
from
    dbo.tblcourse tc
    JOIN
    dbo.tblusereg ur ON tc.courseid = ur.[course-id]
    JOIN
    dbo.UserCourse uc ON ur.[course-id] = uc.[course-id]
where
    ur.userid=@userid 
    and 
    uc.[date] is not null
```

This *may* fix your problem...

Comment: @gbn - I still don't see how the original query could lead to duplicate records? Could you explain that further *(read as: dumb down enough to get on my level)*?

Comment: @Lieven: Perhaps because of many `uc.date` values per `tc.coursename` due to the CROSS JOIN between tc and uc. The ur1 subquery in theory does some restriction, but this would be bollixed by the cross join. Or what if `course` is a number and `id` is unambiguous: `course-id` is a subtraction when it should be `[course-id]` as a column name. Or something else (poor data quality etc). I'm just guessing...

Comment: @gbn: OP can `CROSS JOIN` his heart out but if he does a `DISTINCT` over the final result, I still don't get how he could get duplicate records. I would really love to see OP post two if those *duplicate* records.

Comment: @Lieven: what if the CROSS JOIN adds a lot of non-distinct values for uc.date?

Comment: @gbn: then those are not *duplicate records*?!

Comment: @Lieven: exactly! What the OP *thinks* is DISTINCT (per column) isn't because of this. I'm *guessing* that if the JOINs were correct then the query would behave as expected

Answer (score 0):

Change that first part of your query

```
select distinct (tc.coursename),
```

TO

```
select distinct tc.coursename,
```

to make all the columns `distinct` not just `tc.coursename`

Comment: i changed it but still i am getting same problem.

Comment: IMHO Your data is not distinct under the hood, what you get in the result is not what exactly saved in DB like the precision of date saved and what you get in the result.